# Default colorscheme loads prior to user-defined one causing "flash"

Tags: vim

When using Gvim on my Ubuntu 12.10, I see a flashing screen (as if the colors are reverted) whenever I hit the top or the bottom of the screen (Suppose I'm on first line and press any movement keys for further motion towards top or left). The screen flashes even when I press Tab or any other movement key. I searched for the problem, it seems very similar to this bug report here:

http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=291415

It doesn't lists any solution. How can I go about fixing this problem.

Note: The terminal version works absolutely fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see is the visual bell and yes, the colors are reverted. See `:help 'visualbell'`.

To disable it, put that line in your `~/.gvimrc`:

```
set vb t_vb=
```